# Heroku push giving me "no Cedar-supported app detected error"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, push

I'm trying to push my RoR to Heroku for the first time (I'm a newbie on this stuff!)
The error that I'm getting is:

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:calm-retreat-9405.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:calm-retreat-9405.git'
```

Comment: Can you do a push to your git repository?

Comment: Are you the only person doing pushes to your Heroku? That usually makes some changes conflict with your local/remote repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double check if you committed correctly your Gemfile and config.ru